# Can you directly call functions in command line?

Tags: c, linux, command-line

For example, if I have the following function

```
void printText(char text [100]){
    printf("%d", text);
}
```

could I then do this in the command line

```
printText(Hello World)
```

and then get my expected output as

```
Hello World
```

Comment: This is not straightaway possible in C. You need to have some sort of daemon waiting to read your command line inputs - possible, that's a long shot from being straighforward.

Comment: Is the motivation idle curiosity or do you have a problem you're trying to solve? If so, what is it? There may be a better way to achieve what you need. At any rate, the typical approach is to write a program with `main` around your func and pass the input in as an argument, call the func and print the result to stdout where you can pipe it to another program (or whatever you're trying to do here).

Comment: Your shell might support functions, but that's not the correct syntax for either the definition of the function or the call of the function.

Comment: `text` is not an `int`, so `printf("%d", text);` is incorrect

Comment: I think you need a main,  so the easiest answer is to create a program that takes your input as argument and then prints it.

Comment: This is either a teachers question (in which case the answer is "C is a compiled language which cannot do that." or "The commandline is not a C interpreter."). Or it is a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem (as @ggorlen has already hinted).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your shell. Some shells do support functions. In `bash`, the POSIX shell, and probably others, the following is the correct syntax:

```sh
printText() {
   printf '%s\n' "$1"
}

printText 'Hello World'
```

If you meant your question literally, then no, it's not possible to call a function without even mentioning the file in which it's located. The language used to write the function is irrelevant.

But it is possible to compile a C function and have it called from the shell somehow? Yes. If you created a shared library (shared object on unixy systems or DLL on Windows) from the function, you could. It would require a tool to do so, but such a tool could exit. (Windows also supports [COM objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) and a number of derived techs. Some of these might even make the task easier.)

(I can't tell if such tools actually do exist or what they are because software recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow. I will say that such a tool could be built around a library such as [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to rely on `dlopen()`/`LoadLibrary()` and
`dlsym()`/`GetProcAddress()` but you cannot ensure the function
prototype conforms to your expectation.

A more robust solution consists in providing a lookup table filled
with functions that you know are compliant with the intended usage.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined

  $ ./prog_c printText "Hello world"
  printText --> <Hello world>
  $ ./prog_c textLen "Hello world"
  textLen --> 11
  $ ./prog_c what "Hello world"
  cannot find function 'what'
**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void
printText(const char *text)
{
  printf("printText --> <%s>\n", text);
}

void
textLen(const char *text)
{
  printf("textLen --> %d\n", (int)strlen(text));
}

typedef struct
{
  const char *name;
  void (*fnct)(const char *);
} TextFunction;

bool // success
call_text_function(const char *name,
                   const char *arg)
{
  static TextFunction table[]={ {"printText", printText},
                                {"textLen",   textLen},
                                {NULL,        NULL} };
  for(int i=0; table[i].name!=NULL; ++i)
  {
    if(strcmp(table[i].name, name)==0)
    {
      table[i].fnct(arg);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int
main(int argc,
     char **argv)
{
  if(argc!=3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s function arg\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  if(!call_text_function(argv[1], argv[2]))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot find function '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```